# Management of system directory in linux using git

Tags: linux, puppet, git, sudo

I'm using puppet to manage my linux systems.
I have to use /etc/puppet directory to keep manifest files instead of user home directory, and I want to manage them by git. But because /etc/puppet's owner is root, after I execute 'sudo git init', I always need to use sudo for writing(git add, git commit, etc).

1. Are there any way to avoid using sudo? If I have to manage system directory using git, do I have to always use it?
2. Is it OK to use sudo using git repeatedly? I've never done that, because I always edited source files in my home directories.

Answer (score 1):

Puppet makes some assumptions about the permissions of some files in `/etc/puppet` (and the directory itself, I believe). As such, you likely will not be able to make that location writeable to your regular account.

This is usually not a good choice anyway. If you want to work in `/etc/puppet` directly, you **should work as root** - sudo is an ill fit here. Try `sudo su` or `sudo -i`.

Note that you **can** make Puppet read manifests from locations outside of `/etc` if you set appropriate

- [manifestdir](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/configuration.html#manifestdir) and
- [modulepath](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/configuration.html#modulepath)

options in `puppet.conf`.